# very basic c++: seg fault when doing cross class pointer assignment with malloc

Tags: c++

In the following code, 'buf' is malloced, but then why accessing its member gives seg fault?

```
class tool{
   ...
   void do(char* buf){
        buf = malloc(100);
        ... //init buf[0], buf[1], etc
   }
};

class user{
   ...
   tool  *tl;
   char  *buf;

   user(){

       tl = new tool;
       tl -> do(buf);

       cout<<buf[1]<<endl;  //---> gives seg fault!  Why?
   }
};
```

Answer (score 9):

You didn't write to the copy of `buf` in `user`. All you did was allocate the memory, store it to a local variable in `do()` and then forget about it when `do()` returned.

You need `do()` to receive a `char**`. Only if you do it this way can `do()` return the newly allocated memory to the caller.

```
void _do(char** buf){
    *buf = (char*)malloc(100);
    ... //init buf[0], buf[1], etc
}
...
tl -> _do(&buf);
```

Of course, since this is C++ I wonder why you don't use references and `std::string`, but perhaps this is illustrative code.

Comment: Thanks! I am using a char array to read the pixels of a bmp image and send the array to some legacy c code.

Comment: I might be cleaner to write as `buf = t1->do()` to be honest, although this answer is still correct.

Comment: @lukmac: you might consider using `std::vector<char>`, to save having to manage the memory yourself (which is easy to get wrong). You can easily get a C-compatible pointer to its contents: `&vector[0]` (or `vector.data()` in C++11).

Comment: Alternatively, pass the pointer by reference: `void do( char *& buf ) { buf = (char*)malloc(100); }`